# Not able to understand the output value of time after using the window function?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, time, window

I was trying to find out the time window in which my dataframes values lie, but i am not able to understand the output. I am not able to understand how the:
**window(timeColumn, windowDuration, slideDuration=None, startTime=None)** is working.

This is the code:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("0000-01-01 00:00:00", 1),("1970-01-01 19:02:34", 1),("1970-01-01 19:01:29", 1)]).toDF("date", "val")
from pyspark.sql.functions import window
w = df.groupBy(window("date", windowDuration="55 seconds")).sum("val").alias("sum")
display(w)
```

Using databricks.

Can someone please tell me the output and explain it how it works.

[image]

Comment: have you read the [official doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.window) ?

Comment: In your code, did you chose the param `windowDuration="55 seconds"` by yourself ? or someone gave it to you? try with `1 minutes` or `2 minutes`, i'm sure you'll understand by yourself how it works. 55 secondes is a bit weird

Comment: @Steven i choose it by my self as i was trying different different cases...in few cases i understood..in some cases i didnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a timestamp column, [`window`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.window) will create a "bucket" (start and end time) that contains the input timestamp. The "size" of the bucket depends on the `windowDuration` duration parameter.

For exemple, you have a timestamp `2021-10-29 11:13:51` and you apply the window function with `windowDuration = "15 minutes"`, the new column will be a struct with  `start = "2021-10-29 11:00:00"` and `end = "2021-10-29 11:15:00"`. Between start and end, you have 15 minutes, and your timestamp is contained in between.

In your current code, you use `windowDuration="55 seconds"`. According to the documentation:

> The startTime is the offset with respect to 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC with which to start window intervals.

It means that from the date 1970-01-01 00:00:00, it will create windows of 55 secondes length. First one will be `1970-01-01 00:00:00 ==> 1970-01-01 00:00:55`, seconde one will be `1970-01-01 00:00:55 ==> 1970-01-01 00:01:50`, etc ...
It works but the start and end are not regular compare to a `1 minutes` param for example.

Comment: but i took one example as "0000-01-01 00:00:00"...way before 1970-01-01 but still it is showing the window.

Comment: @ChitranshMathur it starts at 1970, so if you go below, it's messy. But I doubt you work with data earlier than 1970

Comment: ya i wont be working before that date....but i was just trying to understand the concept and was trying different cases.